# How to specify default search field in SolrJ

Tags: solr, solrj

I need to specify `df` parameter in the query. I am using `SolrQuery` class from SolrJ.

Is there a predefined method to set default search filed in `SolrQuery` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and build the solr query using Solrj as below.

```
final SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
  query.setQuery("title:bloomberg");
  query.setParam("debugQuery", "on");
  query.add("rows", "4");
  query.add("rq", "{!ltr reRankDocs=4 model=6029760550880411648}");
  query.add("fl", "*,score");
  query.add("wt", "json");
  query.addFilterQuery("name : tester1");
```

Also you can use the `CommonParams` API

```
solrQuery.setParam(CommonParams.Q, queryString);
solrQuery.setParam(CommonParams.DF, fieldName);
```

[CommonParams Api link](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_0_0//solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/params/CommonParams.html)

Comment: Thank you. I thought it will be a predefined method, something like `setDefaultSearchField`